# Any reason to fire AFTER UPDATE trigger, if no records were updated?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Consider this SQL script:

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE foo
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(20) NULL
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [foo_insert]
    ON foo
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT COUNT(*) from inserted;
END
GO

INSERT INTO foo VALUES(1, 'Jonh');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(2, 'Mary');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(3, 'Peter');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(4, 'Helen');

SELECT * FROM foo;

CREATE TABLE #bar
(
    Id INT NOT NULL
);

UPDATE
    foo
SET
    foo.Name = NULL
FROM
    #bar JOIN foo ON #bar.Id = foo.Id;

SELECT * FROM foo;
DROP TABLE foo;

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Running it from Management Studio or similar app, you'll get output like this:

[image]

Here `AFTER UPDATE` trigger fires when server executes `UPDATE ... FROM` statement. Since `#bar` is empty, there's nothing to update, but trigger still fires (second result in "Results" pane).

Is there any reason for SQL Server to behave this way?
In other word, I mean, that `AFTER UPDATE` trigger must be, well, after update - that is, after some records were updated? No?

Comment: From [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) `AFTER specifies that the DML trigger is fired only when all operations specified in the triggering SQL statement have executed successfully. ` Was your update successful? Yes - trigger was activated.

Comment: I'm not sure, that term "successful" is applicable for update, that haven't updated anything. Expression was executed successfully, that's true, but there is not updated row. This really confuses.

Comment: Trigger is fired once per statement, no error so it is successful.

Comment: Is identity update A to A successful or not? `UPDATE foo SET Name = Name WHERE Id = 1`? Should be trigger fired or not?

Comment: If there was a [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) column in the table should `update foo set Name = Name;` fire the trigger, otherwise pretend nothing happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

Obviously, there is no critical reason for executing the trigger if no rows are updated.  That is the behavior of most databases.

On the other hand, there is little harm in doing so.  SQL Server uses the `inserted` and `deleted` views to provide the list of rows that are modified.  As you observe, these could be empty.  Most triggers use the contents of `inserted` and `deleted` and do nothing when these are empty.

I could imagine situations where this would be useful, particularly for security and auditing purposes.  This allows `update` triggers to keep track of all updates and attempts at updates.  That is something that can't be done in many other databases.

Comment: Actually, your answer is most reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

It's documented behavior.   Why does it work that way?   You'd have to ask the guy who decided to write it that way.   My guess would be performance.   Triggers are probably quicker if they don't have to check the operation that triggered them to see if it did anything.

You did an UPDATE, fire the UPDATE TRIGGER.   That's fast.

You did an UPDATE, let me check to see if any rows were changed.  No?  Don't fire at all.   That's slower.

Also what happens to the poor coder who wants to have an UPDATE TRIGGER perform a certain action even if no rows were updated?   What about him/her, huh?

Comment: IMO, documentation isn't clear. Moreover, debugging triggers is a pain, and I have spent several hours to find out, that yet another trigger (not mine), fires and raises error due to its logic. Thanks to this MS SQL behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your update is not updating any records.

```
UPDATE
    foo
SET
    foo.Name = NULL
FROM
    #bar JOIN foo ON #bar.Id = foo.Id;
```

You'll get 0 and also you are asking to return all records inserted when there hasn't been any insertions in the current transaction.

If you want to do a count, you will either need a transaction with a loop and some kind of counter or change this `SELECT COUNT(*) from inserted;` to count an specific event.

Comment: I know, that my update updates no records. The question is what trigger is fired for, is there is no updated records.

Comment: No trigger was fired.